# Mouse position in canvas without a library?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I been searching around to find how to get the mouse position relative to canvas but without a JS library...can't see to find any examples except for jquery!

I use this to start my function:

```
 canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");  
 ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"); 
 canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", mousePos, false);
```

But e.pageX and e.pageY is affected by the position of the canvas. I need to remove that issue so the maths is correct so its only based on the canvas.

Can this be done without a JS library? As I have only ever seen it done with jquery which i'm trying to avoid as much as possible.

Comment: You can do everything a JS library can do with plain JS; as the libraries are written in JS. It might not be as clean or simplified, but it is always possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var findPos = function(obj) {
    var curleft = curtop = 0;
    if (obj.offsetParent) { 
        do {
           curleft += obj.offsetLeft;
           curtop += obj.offsetTop; 
        } while (obj = obj.offsetParent);
    }
    return { x : curleft, y : curtop };
};
```

Get the position of the canvas element and subtract the x and y from it.

Comment: I tried it like this :
http://www.paste.to/MzQ5OTgx

But its different syntax to your's im wondering if mine is wrong ?

Comment: Read what it does: it adds up the position of all of the parent elements.

Comment: Yeh just wondering why the syntax is different to mine =/ As i just call a function straight.

Comment: obj is the canvas element, it is not an event object. You made global variables because you need not include the var.

Comment: `function foo()` and `var foo = function()` is basically the same thing.

Comment: Hmm its not changing any thing on my end - let me paste.to it:
http://www.paste.to/MzQ5OTk4

Its suppose to convert mouse to tile grids. It works but the offset is still off even with the subtraction supplied by you're example.

Comment: You should factor in the scroll offset as well.

Comment: @JeffreySweeney that is normally handles with the event's x and y since browsers handle that differently [fiddle example does that]

Comment: Hmm its not working for me curleft and curtop still remain 0 =/

Answer (score 1):

I'm using :

```
var x;
var y;
if (e.pageX || e.pageY)
{
    x = e.pageX;
    y = e.pageY;
}
else {
    x = e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
    y = e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop; 
} 
x -= gCanvasElement.offsetLeft;
y -= gCanvasElement.offsetTop;
```

Comment: how does it get gCanvasElement without it passed in a function ?

Comment: fails if canvas is nested into multiple parents.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to get the offset of the canvas element, or how far right + down it is from the top-left corner.

When the mouse moves, factor in the offset variables to the mouse's position.

This code should do the trick:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");


var xOff=0, yOff=0;



for(var obj = canvas; obj != null; obj = obj.offsetParent) {
    xOff += obj.scrollLeft - obj.offsetLeft;
    yOff += obj.scrollTop - obj.offsetTop;
}



canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {

                        var x = e.x + xOff;
                        var y = e.y + yOff;


                        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
                        ctx.fillText(x + " - " + y, 40, 40);  

                        }, true);
```