# three js controls only in div

Tags: jquery, three.js

I've successfully rendered a 3d object in a div: but I'd like to have the ability to manipulate the 3d object only from the div. Currently I can manipulate (control?) the object from anywhere in the window.

I'm using three JS and JQuery.

I have the following in init():

```
// This <div> will host the canvas for the scene.
container = document.getElementById( 'view_area' );
```

which puts the canvas in view_area nicely, but the controls drag area includes the entire window, so if I try to select text outside view_area it starts animating the scene.

Comment: Take a look here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15108095/three-js-limit-and-scale-mouse-controls-to-canvas-size

Answer (score 6):

Most of the controls accept a 2nd parameter which is the dom element to add the listeners too.

```
controls = new THREE.FirstPersonControls( camera, container );
```